# Fullcalendar triggering multiple sources

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar v2 and the sources of the events are selectable from an ul-li menu. The initial call uses the link from the first li and I may navigate through all the months in the calendar. When I use the second link, fullcalendar retrieves the events from the previous link as well as the new link. On each new select, fullcalendar remember the event sources. How can I disable this? Here my code:

```
$("#chgBranch li").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)

    var urlEvents = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    var branchName = $(this).children('a').text();

    $('#calendarSchedules').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendarSchedules').fullCalendar('removeEventSource');

    // refill calendar
    fillEvents(urlEvents, branchName);
});

function fillEvents(urlEvents, branchName) {

    // change title of potlet box
    var newTitle = '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Available schedules for: ' + branchName;
    $('#calendarCaption').html(newTitle);

    $('#calendarSchedules').fullCalendar({
        year: <?= $yy ?>,
        month: <?= --$mm ?>, // javascript month is 0 based
        date: 1,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next,today'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        firstDay: 1, // monday
        editable: false,
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        dayRender: function (view, element) {
            $('.fc td.fc-sun').css('background', '#E7EFEF');
            $('.fc td.fc-sat').css('background', '#E7EFEF');
        },
        eventClick: function (event) {
            $('#dueTime').show();
            $('#duedate').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#duetime').val(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#isPartitionable').val(event.partitionable); // user clicked on partitionable dispo or not
        }
    });

    $('#calendarSchedules').fullCalendar('addEventSource', urlEvents);
}

// load first branch item
$('#chgBranch li a:first').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should destroy your calendar also. Because you are initializing fullcalendar every tine on sources change from ul-li.

Try below one.

```
$("#chgBranch li").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // To prevent following the link (optional)

    var urlEvents = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    var branchName = $(this).children('a').text();

    $('#calendarCaption').fullCalendar( 'destroy' );

    // refill calendar
    fillEvents(urlEvents, branchName);
});
```

This will work for sure. I tried locally and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with following method which also works fine, but @Chintan method is also fine:

```
$('#calendarSchedules').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
$('#calendarSchedules').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', storedEventSource);
```

And I store the event source in a hidden field once the calendar rendered.